# How to correctly support different C++ STL's in Android Native Builds

Tags: android, c++, makefile, stl, android-ndk

To be honest, i understood that all c++ dependencies must be compiled with same C++ STL & Ndk in Android Project as indicated [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md#Using-Mismatched-Prebuilt-Libraries). but what if i have many dependencies with supporting different C++ STL and NDK  versions. It sounds like no use of it. I believe that there must be accurate way for it.

Firstly, the situation is that there is an android project which builds with many c++ libraries (might be more than 3).  Those are supports different C++ STL and Ndk. Somehow those dependencies was working until decided re-build for some purposes. Such as building old version of v8(v4.9) support **stlport** , POCO supports **gnustl** and etc.

By the way i already tried;

- Building dependencies with certain STL (failed)
- Adding different STL's as Shared Libraries to dependencies such as (Android.mk);

> ```
>     include $(CLEAR_VARS)
> LOCAL_MODULE := stlportshared
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../src/main/jniLibs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libstlport_shared.so
> include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
>
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
> ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
>     LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../libsnative/x86/release/libv8-7dc15a4d5e.a
> else
>     LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../libsnative/armeabi/release/libv8-7dc15a4d5e.a
> endif
> LOCAL_MODULE := v8
> LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := stlportshared
> include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
> ```

Actual APP_STL is gnustl_shared in Application.mk

Note: There is a no compile error but runtime crashes. Crash is **null dereferences** . Intended to ask as superficial but i can forward details of crashes for who are curious.

Comment: Please be careful when using the term "STL", The abbreviation STL stands for [Standard Template Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library), which is in part an inspiration for the first version of the [C++ standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library). They are however not the same.

Comment: Sorry, i have edited.

Comment: "*but what if i have many dependencies with supporting different C++ STL and NDK versions. It sounds like no use of it.*" -- that's more or less an accurate analysis.  Different implementations of the C++ STL are unlikely to interoperate.  Even different versions of the same implementation may not interoperate fully.  Similarly, code built against one version of the C++ STL probably will not interoperate with a different version.  This is a general characteristic of most C++ APIs.

Comment: okey i already accepted it. Looking for  Is there any provided solution or workaround up to now ? suppose there are two dependencies built against different c++ stl. So should i not use them or ?

Comment: That's correct. If you have two libraries built against different STLs you can't use them together. If you can rebuild the libraries, build them all with the same STL. If you can't, there's no other option than to not use those dependencies together.

Comment: At that time somehow i used gnustl as run-time C++ STL against  c++ dependencies compiled with stlport. It sounds like there is no much more differences like layout changes etc. but i cannot figure out why cannot use now and do not know what differences already exist with them. @DanAlbert,  is there a good reason to not use gnustl as run-time c++ STL against stlport ?

Comment: Definitely don't do that. Anything you get working in that configuration works by accident, and almost certainly will in only a few cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there are very strong reasons to use the latest release of NDK. r20 at the time of writing this, and this luckily only has two STL variants supported: **c++_shared** and **c++_static**.

The easiest way to organize your native libraries is to build them all with **c++_shared**.

I understand that you have encountered some problems with this approach. Fixing these problems may be helpful in the long run, because these problems may be symptoms of some internal troubles in your code.

But if you cannot, don't dispair.

Your app can safely use different mative libraries, each built with its own STL, as long as it does not mix these native libs. If you have Java class **A** that has native methods in **libA.so** and class **B** with its own **libB.so**, and there are no calls from **libA.so** to **libB.so** or vice versa, you should not care which STL is used by **libA.so** and which - by **libB.so**.

Furthermore, if you have native library libQ.so that calls C functions in libP.so, then you don't care whether **libP** or **libQ** use STL at all, or which STL each of them uses. But this is true if these C functions are not C++ functions in disguise. They should not pass C++ objects (including **std::string**). They should not receive or return pointers to C++ objects (even if the C API uses **reinterpret_cast** for **void ***.

Note that for most practical purposes, the rules for libraries built with **c++_static** are same. Two such libraries should not pass C++ objects from one to the other.

Comment: As you suggest, at the end, i will upgrade the ndk version and  compile all dependencies with same STL. Thank you guys.. these answers making the decision easier.